# Cannot resolve symbol Callbacks in Android Studio

Tags: android, callback, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 0.3.7 and I used ListFragment wizard in this version of Android Studio recently. ListFragment was generated successfully but there is an error in class javadoc: Cannot resolve symbol 'Callbacks'. This is not a compilation or runtime error but I do not understand that Callbacks interface does not exists in the Android SDK. Also I want to know the host activity must implement which interface exactly. Any help is appreciated. My list fragment:

```
/**
* A fragment representing a list of Items.
* <p />
* <p />
* Activities containing this fragment MUST implement the {@link Callbacks}
* interface.
*/
public class UyeIslemHacmiFragment extends ListFragment {

private int mUyeNo;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public static UyeIslemHacmiFragment newInstance(int uyeNo) {
    UyeIslemHacmiFragment fragment = new UyeIslemHacmiFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(Constants.ARG_UYE_NO, uyeNo);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public UyeIslemHacmiFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mUyeNo = getArguments().getInt(Constants.ARG_UYE_NO);
    }

    // TODO: Change Adapter to display your content
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, DummyContent.ITEMS));
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
            + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}


@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    if (null != mListener) {
        // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
        // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).id);
    }
}

/**
* This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
* fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
* to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
* activity.
* <p>
* See the Android Training lesson <a href=
* "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
* >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
*/
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onFragmentInteraction(String id);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Javadoc error is that it can't find the `Callbacks` class and isn't able to resolve the reference in the `{@link Callbacks}` Javadoc tag. This isn't a compile error because problems in comments don't rise to the level of errors.

It looks like the template for this wizard is a little broken; I've filed https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63593 for it. For the time being I think you can delete that part of the Javadoc.

Comment: Maybe it can be `{@link UyeIslemHacmiFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener}`, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.spanishestate.propertiesforsale;

        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.webkit.WebView;
        import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
        import android.widget.ProgressBar;
        import android.net.Uri;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE=1;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent intent) {
        if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
        {
            if (null == mUploadMessage) return;
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null
                    : intent.getData();
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        webView = new WebView(this);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/199/index.html");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
        {
            //The undocumented magic method override
            //Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here
            // For Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {

                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                MyWb.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

            }

            // For Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser( ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType ) {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                MyWb.this.startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                        FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }

            //For Android 4.1
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                MyWb.this.startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser( i, "File Chooser" ), MyWb.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE );

            }

        });


        setContentView(webView);


    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    //flipscreen not loading again
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

// To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
/*@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
        web.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}*/
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.